# Why does Object.prototype not set the value of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

I was playing around with javascript in my web browser when I noticed something strange.
I defined a class *TestClass* like this:

```
class TestClass{};
var testObj=new TestClass();
Object.setPrototypeOf(testObj, null);
```

When I `console.log`ed testObj, there were no properties.

Here is where I became confused.
`typeof testObj` returned `"object"`. But when I ran the following:

```
Object.prototype.testProperty='testing';
```

`testObj` didn't have the property `testProperty`, even though I'd defined it for all objects and according to `typeof`, `testObj` was an object.

Why is this happening? Don't all values inherit properties from `Object`?

This also happens for `[[Scopes]]` objects. When, in chrome, I `console.log` a function and I save its `[[Scopes]]` property as a global variable, `typeof` returns `"object"` but the global variable does not have the property `testProperty`.

Comment: You *removed* the prototype from `testObj`. It's not "inheriting" anything from anywhere any more, since the prototype chain is empty (well, `null` but same thing).

Comment: Also `typeof x //"object"` does not mean it *inherits* from the Object prototype. It just means it's an object, that's it.

Comment: inheritance is based on prototype links, so if you remove it, why do you still expect the inheritance? `typeof` has nothing to do with inheritance. You would need to check with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't all values inherit properties from `Object`?

No. *Most* objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, but some don't - like the `Object.prototype` object itself. Also objects whose prototype was explicitly set to `null`, like the `testObj` one you created in your code or a `Object.create(null)`. Other cases are objects from different realms, which inherit from a *different* `Object.prototype` object.